# addEventListener getting ignored

Tags: javascript, loops, listener

I have a loop that adds elements to a dropdown. 
The elements get added, and I want to add an event that happens when the user clicks on one of the elements.
So I am adding an event listener like this.

```
for (var i = 0; cities.length > i; i++) {
        if (cities[i].toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) !== -1 && citiesList <= 10) {
            citiesList ++;
            dropdown.classList.add('show');
            dropdown.innerHTML += '<a class="dropdown-item" id="dropdown_item-' + i + '" href="#">' + cities[i] + '</a>';
            var item = document.getElementById('dropdown_item-' + i);
            item.addEventListener("click", function(){ console.log("test") });
            console.log(item);
        }
    }
```

But when I click on the elements the event does not fire even though console.log logs the item correctly and when I add the listener manually through the console it works. I tried using a timeout function but to no prevail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you `+=` with the `innerHTML` of a container, the container's contents get completely re-parsed from their HTML markup alone. Anything else (such as event listeners not in the HTML markup) will be lost. Use [`insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) instead:

> The insertAdjacentHTML() method of the Element interface parses the specified text as HTML or XML and inserts the resulting nodes into the DOM tree at a specified position. It does not reparse the element it is being used on, and thus it does not corrupt the existing elements inside that element. This avoids the extra step of serialization, making it much faster than direct innerHTML manipulation.

```
dropdown.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<a class="dropdown-item" id="dropdown_item-' + i + '" href="#">' + cities[i] + '</a>');
```

That said, it looks like you may be giving the element an ID just so that you can select it and subsequently attach a listener to it. Dynamic IDs are a pretty bad idea - if the reason for the ID, it would be better to create the element using `createElement` instead:

```
const a = document.createElement('a');
a.className = "dropdown-item";
a.textContent = cities[i];
a.addEventListener("click", function() {
  console.log("test")
});
dropdown.appendChild(a);
```

Keep in mind that `i` will equal to `cities.length` after the end of the loop, given your current code. If you reference `i` inside the listener callback, if you want it to reference the `i` used for that particular iteration, you need a block-scoped `i` instead: change

```
for (var i = 0; cities.length > i; i++) {
```

to

```
for (let i = 0; cities.length > i; i++) {
```

(or, even better, use `Array.prototype.forEach` or something like that instead of manually messing with indicies)